# Do adversarial neural networks exist in the brain?

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, neural-network

A recent development in Artificial Neural Networks for machine learning applications is the use of Adversarial Networks ([see this paper for an example](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07379v1.pdf)). Adversarial Networks is a network architecture where one network learns to "fool" the other.

Does this type of adversarial learning exist in the brain at a neuronal level?